# PrimeFaces disabled input opacity

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

Could someone help me with changing opacity of disabled inputText?

```
<div class="ui-grid-col ui-grid-col-8">
        <p:inputText disabled="true" value="#{someValue}"/>
</div>
```

In my css file I tried

```
.ui-state-disabled {
    opacity: 0.95;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=95);
    cursor: default !important;
}
```

for example, but it has no effect at all, how can I make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript. 
add make a style for this with a special class.
like:

```
.disable-input{
 opacity: 0.95;
 filter: Alpha(Opacity=95);
 }
```

then check the input if it's disabled:

```
var input = document.getElementById('inputId');
if(input.disabled){
 input.classList.add("disable-input");
}
```

Hope that help you

Comment: Why adding a class for this? PrimeFaces already did all the hard labour.

Comment: I've never used it before!, so maybe more complex than adding a class.